# Как сделать слайдер с селектом что бы при нажатии на категорию показывались только те картинки которые относятъся к категории

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Надо реализовать слайдер с селектом. Есть селект c категориями. При выборе категории нужно что-бы картинки были на слайдере относящиеся только к выбранной категории.

Есть вот такая html разметка.

```
<div class="style__box">
  <div class="style__item">
    <div class="style-select">
       <select name="clothing-select" class="js-choice">
          <option value="Спортивный стиль">Спортивный стиль</option>
          <option value="Классический стиль">Классический стиль</option>
          <option value="Романтический стиль">Романтический стиль</option>
          <option value="Современный стиль">Современный стиль</option>
          <option value="Этно стиль">Этно стиль</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="style-slider swiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="assets/images/fashion-news/sport-styles/sport-style-1.png" alt="sport-style"/>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="assets/images/fashion-news/sport-styles/sport-style-2.jpg" alt="sport-style"/>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="assets/images/fashion-news/sport-styles/sport-style-3.jpg" alt="sport-style"/>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="assets/images/fashion-news/sport-styles/sport-style-4.jpg" alt="sport-style"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Слайдер реализован на swiper.js

```
const multiSlider = () => {
  const styleSliders = document.querySelectorAll('.style__item');
  styleSliders.forEach((item) => {
    const slider = new Swiper(item.querySelector('.style-slider'), {
      navigation: {
        nextEl: item.querySelector('.style-button-next'),
        prevEl: item.querySelector('.style-button-prev'),
      },
    });
  });
  console.log(styleSliders);
};

multiSlider();
```